# Syntax error while executing if and select statement in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning basic VBA. When executing the below program in Excel 2013, I am getting a syntax error every time.

```
Sub ShowDiscount3()    
    Dim Quantity As Integer    
    Dim Discount As Double

    Quantity = InputBox(“Enter  the quantity “)    
    Select Case Quantity    
    Case 0 To 24    
        Discount = 0.1    
    Case 25 To 49    
        Discount = 0.15    
    Case 50 To 74    
        Discount = 0.2      
    Case Is >= 75    
        Discount = 0.25    
    End Select    
    MsgBox “Discount: “ & Discount    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to be more specific - [edit] your question to include the exact error message (including line number).  Without investigating further it does look like you have written `“` instead of `"` to quote your strings...

Answer (score 2):

Do not use: `“`

Use `"` instead:

```
Sub ShowDiscount3()
    Dim Quantity As Integer
    Dim Discount As Double

    Quantity = InputBox("Enter  the quantity")
    Select Case Quantity
    Case 0 To 24
        Discount = 0.1
    Case 25 To 49
        Discount = 0.15
    Case 50 To 74
        Discount = 0.2
    Case Is >= 75
        Discount = 0.25
    End Select
    MsgBox "Discount: " & Discount
End Sub
```